# Several segmentation faults for different processes

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 18 recently and getting segmentation faults from running different programs such as python and nano.

The syslog looks like this:

```
Feb  4 18:50:04 dmcb-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 5368.279040] nano[12154]: segfault at 56956c2ce1e0 ip 000056056aa019d9 sp 00007ffd0396c478 error 4 in nano[56056a9f2000+3b000]
Feb  4 19:37:52 dmcb-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 8236.744267] sshd[12526]: segfault at 7fa9094e29d8 ip 00007fed092ec749 sp 00007ffde26ffaf0 error 4 in ld-2.27.so[7fed092db000+27000]
Feb  4 19:37:52 dmcb-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 8237.023587] apport[12529]: segfault at 80009d45e9 ip 000000000059cc34 sp 00007ffd65dbeda8 error 4 in python3.6[400000+3b4000]
Feb  5 07:22:02 dmcb-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 4105.284518] gsd-xsettings[8718]: segfault at 7f1d280095ac ip 00007f3d3f6001d8 sp 00007ffe6b79a5f0 error 4 in libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4[7f3d3f5b4000+114000]
```

I am currently debugging this error but is not sure what the problem is.
Since segmentation fault comes from different processes randomly, I am supposing hardware is the cause.

Some insights would really help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first instinct is correct. The only thing I can think of that would be causing this many segfaults on a completely base system is some kind of hardware problem.

The first thing you check is your memory. Get a copy of [Memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) and let it run for a few hours undisturbed. *Any* errors in Memtest86 means you have bad RAM that needs replaced.

If that turns nothing up, check your power supply next. Bad power will cause "random" errors that can be very hard to otherwise diagnose.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I did not solve the problem completely yet, but I ran memtest86+ and found there were many errors. I think replacing the RAM would be the solution.

Comment: Good going - RAM replacement will probably solve the problem. Good luck!